# Alfresco - How to open .ply file using web-preview?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to preview CAD files on the alfresco, how can I do it?

When I convert .ply file to .stl using transformer, it gets converted successfully but could not preview in the Alfresco web previewer.
I tried to see the properties of the created not using node browser in alfresco, it does not show any thumbnail property.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please describe more in detail what you have done/achieved so far? By default Alfresco can only use renditions for Preview if they are of filetype image, pdf, swf. So if your transformer 'only' converts to ply you still need to convert to pdf or image. In case of an image loftux's soltion is a perfect addon to view highres images in the browser in a very fast manner.

Comment: actually we want to achieve to preview 3D file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a commercial solution?
https://loftux.nu/share/s/Kx9pmszJT6GyX7sdn-4hDw

Comment: i have tried and i am little bit success but the problem is it is not viewing in document detail.node is perfectly created and thumbnail is also created with proper object but that thumbnail is not viewing in preview.